# Qt android 200+ gradle errors when building

Tags: android, qt, gradle, qtquick2, qt-quick

I am trying to setup android in qt.
After following this tutorial [Qt tuturial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=421&v=5OiIqFTjUZI&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.qt.io%2F&embeds_referring_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.qt.io&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjY&feature=emb_logo) every android and openSSL settings are ok. Creating and launching emulator also works but when i try to build any project (i tried qt android tagged example and new empty project configured for android 86x_64) i get 200+ errors[errors 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnPRd.png)[errors 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPv8M.png)[errors 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPKPQ.png)

```
ERROR:*-Android_Qt_6_6_0_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\org\qtproject\qt\android\bindings\QtLoader$2.class: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:*-Android_Qt_6_6_0_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\org\qtproject\qt\android\bindings\QtLoader$1.class: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutionException: There were multiple failures while executing work items
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.workerExecutionException(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:221)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:201)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.doProcess(DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.kt:220)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTask.doTaskAction(DexArchiveBuilderTask.kt:224)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:319)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)

///repeating errors///
        
    Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexBuilderDebug'.
  There were multiple failures while executing work items
     A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
        Failed to process: *-Android_Qt_6_6_0_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes
     A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: *-Android_Qt_6_6_0_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Run with --scan to get full insights.
  Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

I also tried installing everything from android studio not using qt creator for SDK setup. I always get the same error.

Comment: I am faced with the same problem. Did you find the reason?

Comment: Using JDK 17 worked for me too, I found the solution here
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-119223

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out how to fix it. Following qt tutorial they install NDK 21 and for their version it might work but as im using android 34 i need to use NDK 17. After deleting whole Android folder where SDK is and setting everything up again but with NDK 17 it worked for me.

[what i followed](https://forum.qt.io/topic/151244/online-installed-android-qt-6-6-but-build-requires-newer-version)

Answer (score 0):

Using JDK 17 worked for me I found the solution here
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-119223